# how to design health check system for services is down or up

Tags: laravel, microservices, health-check

I have created a laravel project with microservices and now I want to give me a notification whenever any service goes down, but I have no idea how to do this. My question now is how to design a healthCheck for this? Is it a good idea to use an event listener? pleas help me!

Comment: Typically a health check would just be a call to an endpoint (sometimes a very lightweight endpoint that is implemented for this purpose). If the call succeeds (i.e. responds in a reasonable time with a success status code) the service is up, otherwise it's down. Not sure how you envisage an event listener to fit into all of this, of course it can be involved if you want but normally the health check is done by a service specifically built for this purpose (most hosting providers like e.g. AWS can provide with a health checking service).

Comment: Another idea that has been suggested to me is that i use a scheduled job with a list of services to ping; if a service does not respond with a success response code; then raise a Notification. but i dont know how to implement that, That is, I don't know how to run the list of services in Job

Comment: use horizon for running multiple services. and such kind of technic we call `heartbeat`. create a `HEAD` type api request to confirm the app is running or not. However if you want to know any particular service is down or not, then such kind of concept can be done from the server side.

Comment: @Sachin KumarI proposed both my idea and your idea to the project manager, but it was not accepted and he told me that I want a healthcheck system that will notify me when the entire service or server or machine is down. Neither the job will be executed nor the package will be executed. In this case, how can we notice the failure of that service.
I am totally confused how to create a healthcheck system with these conditions